# What is the correct way to check if an instant is on a specific date

Tags: date, datetime, groovy

I have an event, call it A, that occurs at an instant (timestamp, datatime) stored as seconds + milliseconds since the epoch (Jan 1, 1970). I want to find other events that occur on the same Date as event A. What is the best way to represent the target date, and then efficiently check each incoming event for target date.

Comment: Convert it to a jodatime or Java 8 localdate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have an event, call it A, that occurs at an instant (timestamp, datatime) stored as seconds + milliseconds since the epoch (Jan 1, 1970).

You haven't made it clear what type is used to represent the instant, so I'll assume it's a `Long` representing the number of millisecods since Jan 1, 1970.

```
Long event = getEventInstant()
Date targetDate = getTargetDate().clearTime()

if (new Date(event).clearTime() == targetDate) {
    println "they're on the same day"
}
```